# how to switch to new git account temporarily without setting username and password globally

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Let's say I'm using GitLab account 'A' & I have set the user name and password globally.
Now, Assume that I need to switch to GitLab account 'B'.

Is it possible to open a terminal like we open `incognito window` in the browser and log in with new Github account details and push or pull the code? and then close the terminal without losing any global setting for the old account 'A'.

I don't want to set-up two Github accounts. But, when I got some new temporary freelancer tasks, I'm looking for a way to open a new terminal and do Github operations on temporary projects.

Edit:

- My main work is on GitLab So, I have setup username & password for this account.
- I used to work on Temporary projects on GitHub which I don't want to save user credintials globally.
- I'm looking for an Incognito kind of terminal that forcefully asks username and password to interact with GitHub.
- And when I close it, The GitLab account should be assessed with the terminal as usual.

*sorry for my bad english. let's say you login into google then when you open the incognito window. it will ask you to login again. So, for temporary thing people use Incognito window. Similar thing I want in GitHub. Is it possible?*

Comment: Are you thinking locally as in being able to `git push` to GitHub B for a given repo as user B? There are ways to configure local settings in `git config`.

Comment: Do you want to switch to new **credentials** (a username/password which allows you to fetch/pull from a repo) ? or do you want to switch the **author field in your commits** (the name and email that get displayed when viewing the commit list in a repo) ?

Comment: @astrochun I don't want to do inter-account operations. Sometimes I'll get a freelancer project who has GitHub account. I just want to go there finish the work and close without affecting my company credential settings.

Comment: @LeGEC I need to open a terminal. And somehow it should ask me username and password forcefully. So, that i'll login into it work finish close. without affecting my company settings.

Comment: @VikasAcharya : ok. Can you explain in your question : 1. How you access your company gitlab ? (through ssh ?) 2. how are the credentials stored ? (ssh key mentioned in .ssh/config ? git credential manager ?)

Comment: This is answered [in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq), both for HTTPS and SSH.